gnu screen how log windows into different files
Have a few screen sessions for different projects.
Each session has a few windows.
I am trying to log each window in a session into different files.
I made a cron job that updates log file names daily.
Here is how I do this:.
nwd=$(date +%Y%m%d)
screen -S A -p 3 -X log off                                                                                                                                                                                                                   screen -S A -p 3 -X logfile $LOGROOT/A3/$yrmn/A3_${nwd}.log                                                                                                                                       screen -S A -p 3 -X logfile flush 1                                                                                                           screen -S A -p 3 -X logtstamp on                                                                                                             screen -S A -p 3 -X logtstamp after 10                                                                                                       screen -S A -p 3 -X logtstamp string '\n-- %Y-%m-%d %c:%s -- \n'                                                                             screen -S A -p 3 -X log on
screen -S A -p 5 -X log off                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        screen -S A -p 5 -X logfile $LOGROOT/A5/$yrmn/A5_${nwd}.log                                                                                                                                                                                                                      screen -S A -p 5 -X logfile flush 1                                                                                                          screen -S A -p 5 -X logtstamp on                                                                                                             screen -S A -p 5 -X logtstamp after 10                                                                                                       screen -S A -p 5 -X logtstamp string '\n-- %Y-%m-%d %c:%s -- \n'                                                                             screen -S A -p 5 -X log on
The problem is that the screen saves only the last window (A 5).
Any solutions?
